# Deep list count - count lists within lists

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am trying to get the length of a list, but that list can contain other lists that are deeply nested (e.g. `[[[[[[[]]]]]]]`).

But you have to get any non list elements in the count as well: `[1, 2, [3, 4]]` would output 5 (1, 2, 3, 4 and a list). `["a", "b", ["c", "d", ["e"]]]` would output 7.

It first comes to mind to use recursion to solve this problem.
I wrote this:

```
def deep_count(arr, count=0):
    if any(type(i) == list for i in arr):
        for i in arr:
            if type(i) == list:
                count += len(arr)
            else:
                count += 1
        return deep_count(arr[1:], count)
    return count
```

It's outputting 9 instead of 7. And if it's just nested lists like `[[[]]]` it only outputs 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a need for supplying an initial value, you can just use `arr` as the only parameter, then just get the count and if the current element is a list then also add that list's count.

```
def f(arr):
    count = len(arr)
    for element in arr:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            count += f(element)
    return count
```

---

```
>>> f([1, 2, [3, 4]])
5
>>> f(["a", "b", ["c", "d", ["e"]]])
7
```

Comment: Could also start with `count = len(arr)`.

Comment: Hmm, yes, although wouldn't you be looping over the elements 2x?

Comment: Why? Do you think `len` "loops" and counts?

Comment: Ha, I just realized that your *text* has actually been saying that all along :-) ("get the count and [then add the counts of sublists]")

Comment: Yea, but the code was just not the same as it is now. Thank you for the insight. Very knowledgable you are!

Answer (score 4):

Recursively adding all the list lengths ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYwxDsMgFEN3TmExgcrSpkPVq6AMaQLql9IfBEQip6eQoVM9WJaf5XDk98bDI8RaF@fhVUn6KdAUXd4jY3XcO1yQ9o9qXMNvEQXEKOlc/hV5UCJOeeLZqWKwUspaCxEicW5H9mpwM7CDwX0cG/kBOUkD@Wpm5dzjckYnx76r9Qs)):

```
def f(xs):
    return len(xs) + sum(f(x) for x in xs
                         if isinstance(x, list))
```

A variation ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYoxDgIhFER7TjGhgvgbXQvjVQgFLhBJdr8E2ERPj2DhFJPJvJc/7fni5ZZL7z5ERPWu@i4wUkI7CiPVxLU5XsNAhC3VpuHYYws8ZZxQj13tLqtIGIcWIpfETUVlzoQLwSyEq7WD/IF0kiAfo4xc5/S/GaSdXu9f)):

```
def f(xs):
    return isinstance(xs, list) and len(xs) + sum(map(f, xs))
```

Comment: I like this solution. Simple, and to the point.

Comment: Indeed a very pretty solution, although less efficient than the standard loop approaches in my answer. At least from my tests. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZHBioMwEIbveYohp0g9rHpZCn2SIkvUCQ2YKMkI3ad3k5hWC4XCegiTmX/m/ybOv3SbbPM9u3VVbjJA2qAm0GaeHOUbYwMqUJWQzhVnBuHzS/fTT4sluMBXyuhnpCYHugQc0WAQaAtoF4NOEsYJJVR5SGpToL22nqTtUeSeEkbt6aB6tTxdIkzWFknkkBZnA8Rp12Xs@oD9ihxBD5RBtjs@nap/oO6Y9VvMDS8mNsRG3H0e8VhkN7r77AHSDjCijeK0pxFGzkI1JYRMwcK@kmTY7solL4F34bjyPoZDCpG3bctmpy2J7c@KUZpukOf4nrG5CGPe1@sP9eZRX9c/ "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jab Hmm, you' only measured my second solution...

Comment: @Jab Although yes, both are slower. Weren't intended to be fast. And my original suggestion [`f2b` wins](https://tio.run/##nZLdaoQwEIXvfYrBq8h6UX8uysI@ySIl0QkNmChJBPv0Nonpqu1SYXMh48w5cz5Cxi/7OajqfdTLwvUgwQqJwoKQ46Bt/EuSDjnwglCts2sC7piJfbTDpCzc4C10xKPigwaRA/Yo0QmEAlSTRE0t@g05FHFJsHEQRihjqWqRRE8OvTB2pzpGXm4eJmqzINJoJ60cxGXTRexyh31E9qA7SifbEh9JxQuoG2b5FHPFg8jHngD2qEL3lPMlKPYP1QpVkdlEf5x6ItcLFyyJF2QBbPZIszlEHc6RcI5sIXnNqv9k7fUmGoCq7heEpCPhde7S3ToHTi11V3dPaZpDytznnra@7EKJadM0yaiFsmR916SnknX06l@TN2duzfN5eTZnJ4LqZF7/zJflGw) :-)

Answer (score 2):

When talking recursion, always think of the base case (which case would not make a recursion). In your problem, it would be when the list is empty, then it would return a count of 0.

So you could start implementing it like so:

```py
def f(arr):
    if arr == []:
        return 0
```

For the rest of the implementation, you have two approaches:

- Looping over the list and add `f(sublist)` to the count when it is effectively a sublist, and add `1` when it isn't
- Go full recursion and always call the `f(x)` function, no matter if it is a sublist or not, and always add the result to the count. In this case, you have a new base case where `f(not_a_list)` would return `1`

I think this should unstuck you

Note: I just read that recursion is not required, you came up with it. I think this is a good approach for this kind of problem

Comment: more idiomatically in python, `if not arr: ...` not `if arr == []`

Comment: Usually I would agree, but for the second approach it would return 0 when the argument is `0` or `""` as well

Answer (score 1):

My old answer takes the result of the last example of OP as the expected output. If it is not considered, the answer is very simple:

```
>>> def count_deep_list(lst):
...     return sum(count_deep_list(val) for val in lst if isinstance(val, list)) + len(lst)
...
>>> count_deep_list([1, 2, [3, 4]])
5
>>> count_deep_list(["a", "b", ["c", "d", ["e"]]])
7
>>> count_deep_list([[[]]])
2
```

**Old Answer**:

It seems that you need a special judgment on the internal empty list and the incoming list itself. I think it needs to be implemented with the help of closure:

```
>>> def count_deep_list(lst):
...     def count(_lst):
...         if isinstance(_lst, list):
...             if not _lst:
...                 return 0
...             else:
...                 return sum(map(count, _lst)) + 1
...         else:
...             return 1
...
...     return count(lst) - 1 if lst else 0
...
>>> count_deep_list([1, 2, [3, 4]])
5
>>> count_deep_list(["a", "b", ["c", "d", ["e"]]])
7
>>> count_deep_list([[[]]])
1
```

Simpler implementation:

```
>>> def count_deep_list(lst):
...     def count(_lst):
...         return sum(count(val) if val else -1 for val in _lst if isinstance(val, list)) + len(_lst)

...     return count(lst) if lst else 0
...
>>> count_deep_list([1, 2, [3, 4]])
5
>>> count_deep_list(["a", "b", ["c", "d", ["e"]]])
7
>>> count_deep_list([[[]]])
1
```

Comment: Your output for `[[[]]]` shows that you get the same wrong result 1 that the OP reported for their own attempt.

Comment: Sorry, I took that as the expected output of OP. @KellyBundy

Answer (score 1):

A twoline answer would be:

```
def lenrecursive(seq):
    return len(seq) + sum(lenrecursive(s) for s in seq if isinstance(s,Sized) and not isinstance(s, str))
```

However this will not take into account that other things may have a `len`

A more complete handling using EAPF approach is:

```
def lenrecursive(seq):
    """
    Returns total summed length of all elements recursively.
    If no elements support len then return will be 0, no TypeError will be raised
    """
    def _len(x):
        try:
            return len(x)
        except TypeError: #no len
            return 0
    
    try:
        return _len(seq) + sum(lenrecursive(s) for s in seq if not isinstance(s, str))
    except TypeError: #not iterable
        return _len(seq)
```

Notes:

1. Why `not isinstance(s, str)`? - Strings will lead to infinite recursion as a one-character string is a sequence so `lenrecursive(a)` would return `1 + lenrecursive(a)` which is `1 + 1 + lenrecursive(a)` which is `1 + 1 + 1 + ...`
2. Why EAFP using `try: except:` rather than LBYL checking with `isinstance`? - because there are so many things out there that support `len` and you don't know whether the next time you call this you've created a custom class which has a `__len__` but doesn't subclass `Sequence`, `Mapping`, or something else that inherits from `collections.Sized`

Answer (score -1):

```
class Counter:
def __init__(self):
    self.counter = 0

def count_elements(self, l):
    for el in l:
        if type(el) == list:
            self.counter += 1
            self.count_elements(el)
        else:
            self.counter += 1

l = ["a", "b", ["c", "d", ["e"]]]

c = Counter()
c.count_elements(l)
print(c.counter)
```